# git Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: git, gitlab

we have 2 branches 'main' and 'master'.
we do changes in the 'main' branch first, then do a push.
Now, we are ready to merge 'main' into 'master' for prod release. I finished the merge, but I forgot to pull master beforehand. Now when I try to push master(after the merge), I got the error in the title.

I tried pull or fetch master again, still fails with the same message. Used git status on both branches and both say: nothing to commit, working tree clean

What can I do?

update: full error message from GIT GUI interface.

```
Pushing to blah_blah.git
To blah_blah.git
! [rejected]   master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'blah_blah.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: What does the rest of the error say?

Comment: @JimRedmond , I just added the full message in the original post.